# Programmatically implement Mac long-press accent popup

Tags: macos, diacritics

The application I'm working on uses a custom text editor. The problem is that it therefore doesn't employ the Mac's now-standard long-press key accent popup, i.e., holding down 'A' will produce "aaaaaaaaa" instead of the "à á â ä..." window.

Anyone know if it's possible to programmatically call/otherwise implement that accent popup?

Answer (score 0):

Properly handling key events so that they interact properly with the system is discussed in the [Creating a Custom Text View section](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH3-SW24) of the [Cocoa Text Architecture Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/Introduction/Introduction.html). You should also familiarize yourself with the [Handling Key Events chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html) of the [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) (although it's a bit outdated; in particular, it refers to the deprecated `NSTextInput` protocol which has been replaced by `NSTextInputClient`).

The basic gist is that you should send key events through either `-[NSTextInputContext handleEvent:]` or `-[NSResponder interpretKeyEvents:]`, implement action methods on your view, and also have your view class adopt and implement the `NSTextInputClient` protocol.

You acquire a reference to the appropriate `NSTextInputContext` object from the `inputContext` property of `NSView`.

Sending the key events through one of those handler methods is how that press-and-hold feature gets activated. The `NSTextInputClient` protocol methods are how it ultimately interacts with your text view's document model. When the user selects a character from the popover, the feature uses that protocol to actually replace the initial character with the final one.

This will also allow your text view to handle Asian input methods.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. That will definitely give me some things to follow up on.